# Any Ideas on Ways How to Publish Data from Salesforce for External Users?

Tags: customer-portal, experience-cloud, digital-experience, partner-portal, digital

I try to determine the pros and cons of using Experience Cloud, various CMS solutions, or building custom websites for representing Salesforce data for public use. The idea is to build a portal for clients' partners either powered by Experience Cloud / WordPress or any other CMS solution or custom website. Any suggestions on which approach is best?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Just ask ChatGPT

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start with the negative first but try to be as diplomatic as possible:

Experience Cloud and Salesforce CMS are not very robust solutions for authoring and publishing content. To put it politely: Bare minimum functionality, challenging UI and workflows that make it very hard to scale, and a very locked down ecosystem that limit customization and extensibility. Your permissions inside your Salesforce org and your access to Salesforce developer resources (or your ability to do do Salesforce development yourself) will also have a significant impact on your ability to get the most out of Experience Cloud.

On the other hand, if you are locked into a Salesforce ecosystem that is already heavily used and you have access to ample Salesforce admin and dev systems, using Experience Cloud and Salesforce CMS are workable solutions. They are not user-friendly or feature rich, but they work and can be a cost-effective solution.

This is especially true if you are building a site for customer partner users, which it sounds like you are. That's really the best use case for Experience Cloud in my opinion. And if your content already exists inside Salesforce, it will probably be easier to use Experience Cloud to share it with customers and require much less customization than using an external platform like WordPress. In the case of a partner site too, one big advantage that Experience Cloud has over a 3rd party product is the Salesforce security model that is built right into it.

In summary, I would only recommend Experience Cloud for the partner site use case, or if your content exists already in Salesforce, or if your customer support operations are already heavily invested in Salesforce. If not, my recommendation would be to take advantage of Salesforce's robust integration capabilities, which is something they do very well, and connect up an external system that scales better and is more user-friendly.

Comment: Came back here to add this link which has some good suggestions for things to consider before starting an experience cloud site build: https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-experience-cloud-what-i-wish-id-known-before-our-implementation/